# Where are default layout templates stored for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: layouts, arcgis-pro

Previously in ArcMap 10x you could save custom layout MXDs to `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\MapTemplates` or `C:\...\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.3\ArcMap\Templates`. However I can't seem to find a similar directory for ArcGIS Pro, does anyone know if there is a directory for these layouts I think they are .pagx files?

I looked in `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources` and `C:\...\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\ArcGISPro` but couldn't find anything.

My goal is to have custom layouts show in the 'New Layout' window (shown below). I guess its possible Pro creates these on the fly when you click. I realize I can just use the 'Import a layout file' option but it would be cool to have them in the window. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your comment:

> The more I think about it I don't think Pro really pulls these
>   templates from anywhere like in ArcMap, maybe it just generates them
>   onClick (I could be wrong). Even if there was a place these templates
>   are saved I don't think adding a custom layout file to the folder
>   would cause it to be included in the layout window above.

Consequently, if this functionality is important to you I think you will need to [submit an ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas).  I think the title for it would be something like:

> Allow Layout Gallery of ArcGIS Pro to have custom page sizes added to it

---

Somebody submitted an ArcGIS Idea for this titled:

> [Allow Layout Gallery of ArcGIS Pro to have custom page sizes added to it](https://community.esri.com/ideas/14001-allow-layout-gallery-of-arcgis-pro-to-have-custom-page-sizes-added-to-it)

and that idea has been given a status of Implemented at ArcGIS Pro 2.5:

> Custom layouts don't show up from the New Layout dropdown, but you can
>   specify the 'Import gallery path' (a shared network location for an
>   organization using the same templates) which will populate your org's
>   custom layouts from the Import Layout dropdown.

While technically this does not add custom page sizes to the Layout Gallery it does provide an additional gallery of layout templates that you can customize and access using the Import Layout dropdown.

This functionality has been further described in a Esri blog titled [Customize your layout gallery (ArcGIS Pro 2.5)](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/mapping/customize-your-layout-gallery-arcgis-pro-2-5/).